# How to open Local or Global quick action from custom lightning component?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, quickaction

In Winter 17 Salesforce allows creating custom lightning quick actions and have associated interfaces and an event to close the quick action. I wonder if it is possible to invoke the quick action from custom lightning component directly?

Comment: Did you end up discovering if this was possible? :)

Comment: I have the same question

Comment: No I still don't have an answer to that.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it is not even possible to open it through Apex code.

I created two actions. Lightning Action on Account and called it `LA` and Visualforce action on Account and called it `VA`.

When I try to execute this code

```
QuickAction.QuickActionRequest req = new QuickAction.QuickActionRequest();
req.quickActionName = 'Account.LA';
req.contextid = '001xx000003DGcO';
System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR, '@@@ req: ' + req );
QuickAction.QuickActionResult res = QuickAction.performQuickAction(req);
System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR, '@@@ res: ' + res );
```

I receive an error

> System.UnexpectedException: ActionType LightningComponent not
>   supported yet

and when I try to execute this code

```
QuickAction.QuickActionRequest req = new QuickAction.QuickActionRequest();
req.quickActionName = 'Account.LA';
req.contextid = '001xx000003DGcO';
System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR, '@@@ req: ' + req );
QuickAction.QuickActionResult res = QuickAction.performQuickAction(req);
System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR, '@@@ res: ' + res );
```

I receive an error

> System.UnexpectedException: ActionType VisualforcePage not supported
>   yet

So it is not only unavailable directly from Lightning, but it is also unavailable through Apex

Comment: It's an interesting test. I'm not entirely sure what apex could do with these though. Input and output parameters would be challenging to handle.

Comment: Actually I found a workaround for that. If you are interested I may actually post that

Comment: Yes please share your finding, it would be interesting to see what could be done.

Comment: @Patlatus Does URL hacks work for Quick Actions in LEX?

Comment: I think URL hacking doesn't work, actually I even forgot which exact workaround I meant last year

Comment: @Patlatus did you ever remember the workaround? Thanks